# Images not displaying in drupal nodes

Tags: php, drupal-6

I have added some images in the header inside page.tpl.php that shows up fine in the home page as well as /admin. But when I add a page, like /node/1, the images do not display. Please help me...........

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two template file for pages. like front-page.tpl.php and page.tpl.php. So you aslo need to add images in the header inside the front-page.tpl.php.